# Right directory structure for testing

Tags: python, testing, tdd, nosetests

I'm new to Python testing and I want to set up an structure similar to the one you can have when testing Ruby with RSpec. So I followed [this](https://schettino72.wordpress.com/2008/01/19/11/) blog, but it's not working for me. My current structure is:

```
/brute-force
    /source
        __init__.py
        graph.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        test_graph.py
```

**tests/__init__.py:**

```
def setup():
    node1 = Node(1)
    node2 = Node(2)
    graph = Digraph()
    graph.add_node(node1)
    graph.add_node(node2)
    edge = Edge(node1, node2)
    graph.add_connection(edge)
```

**tests/test_graph.py**

```
from source import graph.py
from nose.tools import *
from expects import *


class TestDigraph(object):
    def test_array_is_empty(self):
        expect([]).to(be_empty)
```

[Files on github](https://github.com/FranGoitia/algorithmic-thinking/tree/master/Module%201/brute-force)

When running nosetests on the root `brute-force` directory, it says that 0 tests were run.

Comment: try renaming the `tests` directory to `test`

Comment: nah, it's not that. I have renamed my dir to `tests` and it works. So it must be something else.  Please provide further info. In `test_graph.py` make sure you import correctly `from nose.tools import *` and `from source import graph.py`. Define the `setup` and `teardown` functions/methods at all levels needed (package in `__init__.py`, module, class and method ones in `test_graph.py`)

Comment: Name the test classes properly: e.g. `class TestAirMiles(object):`. Inside them name their methods propery: e.g. `def test_01a_prize_affordable_ok(self):`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I just edited the question and added more information

Comment: please correct you first line in tests/test_graph.py to `from source import graph` (no need for the .py). How do you reference those global variables assigned in the package setup (tests/__init__.py)? Why don't you perform that setup at the module level or at the class level inside tests/test_graph.py?

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to have a look at how I arranged my tests here: https://github.com/pynchia/myair

Comment: oh, sorry for the .py, it was my mistake ahahahaha

Comment: No problem. I tried to use copy your setup but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I Just uploaded the setup to github: https://github.com/FranGoitia/algorithmic-thinking/tree/master/Module%201/brute-force

Comment: ok, I am looking at it now, thank you for the code.

Comment: Right, I lack the expects module and it gives me an error, but nose ran 1 test. I have noticed a few errors: in the tests you instantiate Graph() and not the `Digraph`class. Which is also not declared as inheriting from `object` (well, none of them are)

Comment: I've created a pull request, just fixed those small things for now. I need to go to bed, it's kind of late. I'm sorry. Try it and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for helping me. I just accepted your pull request and download the code you wrote. Still, I run nosetests inside brute-force or inside test folder and it tells me that none tests are run. digraph_test never gets run, I can put syntactically invalid things in that file and python won't complain when running nosetests.